# Always include certain cells regardless of filter: VBAsolution

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, filter, tablefilter

I have a table that has 5 sections of rows (1 for each day of the workweek). Each row header is a staff member's name- there are about 15 people, so 15*5 rows in total. Interspersed are rows titled "Monday" "Tuesday" etc. The column header is called "Name"

Below is the code for the search box:

```
 Sub ScheduleSearch()
    'PURPOSE: Filter Data by Staff Name

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim MyVal As Long
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Schedule").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  mySearch = sht.Shapes("WireSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form


'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
      If myButton.Value = 1 Then
        ButtonName = myButton.Text
        Exit For
      End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  sht.Shapes("WireSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub

Sub ClearScheduleFilter()
'
' ClearScheduleFilter Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Schedule").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

Right now, when I search for Person A, the filter works perfectly and filters the column "Name" by Person A.

**However- I want the cells titled "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" and "Friday" to automatically also be included in this filter no matter what the user searches.**

**Is there a code for this?**

UPDATE: the following code filters the days and week row however it does not filter the mySearch value. Any idea why?

```
'Filter Data
   DataRange.AutoFilter _
   Field:=myField, _
   Criteria1:=Array("MONDAY:", "TUESDAY:", "WEDNESDAY:", "THURSDAY:", "FRIDAY:", "WEEK:", " & mySearch & "), _
   Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: can you provide a sample set of the data (mock up if needed). In this case, I think even a screenshot would suffice, but embedding the data into the question is always best so people can copy/paste.

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, I included a screenshot. As you can see to the left of the image, there are multiple sections of rows within the table. Let me know if this is sufficient- I'm not sure how to embed data within the question.
The textbox on the top of the screen near "Staff Member Filter" is where the user types in a person's name.

Comment: Use Advanced Filter. Keep the day values static and add the searcg criteria on fly.

Comment: @cyboashu I'm a very new to VBA- how would I edit the code above to keep the day values static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the name field, use an Array list to set the filter that includes all the days of the week and the person.

A basic shell is this:

```
Selection.AutoFilter 1, Array("MONDAY", "TUESDAY" , "WEDNESDAY" , "A"), xlFilterValues
```

For the code you've provided this should work:

```
 DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:= Array("MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"," & mySearch & ")", _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: the 3rd line of your suggested code gives me an error. (The criteria1 line). It highlights the ":=" and says "Compile Error. Expected: Expression"

Comment: try now @SRag - I had an extra `"`

Comment: I edited my original post with the code that kind of works. However now it doesn't include the "mysearch" value in the filter- even though the code includes it. Let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: @SRag - I am almost positive you cannot use a combination of like and exact filters in the Array. Either use the exact value of `mySearch` or add `*` for each other filter ... `*MONDAY:*`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman- my bad. When I tried your existing suggestion above it said there was a syntax error and highlighted all 3 lines in red. Any idea why? Thanks for all your help

Comment: @SRag hard to tell without seeing the edit you made, but the syntax is not correct ... probably misplaced quotes or something

Comment: I edited my original post with the code I am now using at the bottom of the question. It gives me no error alert but does not filter for "mySearch". any idea why?

Comment: @SRag change `"=*" & mySearch & "*"` to `"=" & mySearch & ""`